# Sometimes not able to get current url in mobile chromium using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, mobile, chromium

Below is my code. Sometimes driver.getCurrentUrl() returns "about:blank" in that case I am trying to get current url using javascriptexecutor but it also returns "about:blank".
Correct domain name is getting but I need current url and not domain.
Tried with wait, page refresh and javascriptexecutor options as shown in code. But no luck.  Is there any other way to get right current url everytime and not "about:blank"?

```
public void verifyLinks(WebDriver driver, String mainPage, String expectedUrl) {
    try {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        Set<String> a = driver.getWindowHandles();
        System.out.println("window size- " + a.size());
        if (a.size() > 1) {
            switchToNextWindow(driver);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            if (driver.getCurrentUrl().equals("about:blank")) {
                //driver.navigate().refresh();
                //js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");
                String DomainUsingJS = (String) js.executeScript("return document.domain");
                String browserUrl = (String) js.executeScript("return window.top.location.href.toString()");
                String url = js.executeScript("return document.URL;").toString();

                System.out.println("Domain-" + DomainUsingJS);
                System.out.println("Browser url- " + browserUrl);
                System.out.println("url- " + url);
            }
            //softAssert.assertEquals(driver.getCurrentUrl(), expectedUrl);
            System.out.println("GetCurrenturl- " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
            driver.close();
            driver.switchTo().window(mainPage);
        } else {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            driver.navigate().refresh();
            System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
            // softAssert.assertEquals(uiDriver().getDriver().getCurrentUrl(), expectedUrl);
            driver.navigate().back();
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line `returns "about:blank" `?

Comment: driver.getCurrentUrl() returns "about:blank" sometimes (for same links on webpage sometime it returns correct url and sometime it returns "about:blank" so my assert is failing) in that case I tried to use below options but those also returns "about:blank".                                                                                 
String browserUrl = (String) js.executeScript("return window.top.location.href.toString()");                                                                      String url = js.executeScript("return document.URL;").toString();